# CLLocationManager instance in embedded framework not requesting authorization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working on an embedded framework that uses `CLLocationManager` to perform some `BeaconRegion` monitoring. The `CLLocationManager` instance in the framework just won't request authorization from the user. What am I missing?

- The **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** is set in both the app's and the framework's **Info.plist** file, to be sure.
- The app's background capabilities **Location Updates** and **Uses Bluetooth LE accessories** are set.

I am trying to request the authorization like this:

```
- (void)requestPermissionsIfNecessary {
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"_locationManager does not respond to 'requestAlwaysAuthorization'!");
        NSLog(@"CLAuthorizationStatus: %d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);
    } 
}
```

The `_locationManager` does not respond to the selector and the `CLAuthorizationStatus` is 0 (`kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`).

I am testing on an iOS 8.1.1 iPhone 6 Plus.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Now at least I'm able to make the `_locationManager` request authorization. No idea why it is requesting it now.
The `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` delegate method, however, again reports the status of `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. Sounds like an `Info.plist` issue?

Comment: please debug and see the value of _locationManager. Maybe it's nill, or some other class than CCLocationManager ?

Comment: Just did and the _locationManager ivar is properly initialized and of class CLLocationManager. Too bad it wasn't that easy to fix. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delaying the request solved my problem here.

When triggered at the top level by the `viewDidLoad` method of my `rootViewController` it has always been denied. Requesting authorization just a second or so later on a button click worked perfectly. Never experienced this kind of behavior when the `CLLocationManager` was used regularly in a project and not in an embedded framework. In fact I previously used the exact same implementation in a project and everything went fine.